# Подправить простую регулярку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка в обработчике бб-кодов. Такая строка:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#\[img=([^\]]+?)\]http://([^\] \?]+?)\[/img\]#si',
```

Проблема в том, что не поддерживаются картинки с протоколом https://

Делаю так:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#\[img=([^\]]+?)\]http(s*)://([^\] \?]+?)\[/img\]#si',
```

Вообще не работает. Как исправить?

Comment: просто `https?` не надо никаких скобок. А `*` от 0 до бесконечности

Comment: думаю должно работать `s?`

Comment: @Mike верно,спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно помочь. То есть показываем что буква s может быть, а может и не быть.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#\[img=([^\]]+?)\]http(s)?://([^\] \?]+?)\[/img\]#si',
```

Comment: Там уже в комментариях все написали к вопросу. А у вас ненужные круглые скобки, которые сбивают нумерацию захваченных совпадений и последующему коду, который работает по callback снесет крышу. В принципе у ТС возникала именно эта проблема, его `*` не совсем корректно, но все таки сработала бы без скобок

Comment: Согласен. Почему-то я обратил внимание на ошибку в регулярке, но не на callback.